# Add class when page scroll reach at specific id

Tags: jquery

I have an Id in a div `<div id="Section1"> abc </div>` and link `<a id="link" href="#Section1">Section1</a>`

**Question:** When I scroll page and page reach at id `#Section1` a class should be add in the link, link should like`<a id="link" href="#Section1" class="ok">Section1</a>`

Comment: For better understanding, Please provide a **working demo** (*code snippet,jsfiddle ...*)

Comment: have you tried using jquery `ScrollTo()`?

Comment: this might give you an idea..

http://lions-mark.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Comment: I have a single page, with 5 section, I want to highlight link in menu when I scroll page and reach specific section

Comment: @MuhammadRiaz the link that I gave you might give you some idea... take a look at it..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('#link').toggleClass('ok',
     //add 'ok' class when div position match or exceeds else remove the 'ok' class.
      scroll >= $('#Section1').offset().top
    );
});
//trigger the scroll
$(window).scroll();//ensure if you're in current position when page is refreshed
```

See the docs for [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass).

Comment: #Bhojendra Ok Class should be add in link, that has id="link" <a id="link" href="#Section1">Section1</a>

Comment: Oh! Overlooked. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for a nice library, I usually use **[waypoints.js + inview](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/shortcuts/inview/)** for this type of scroll event. It provides a nice API to know when elements enter and leave, etc.

Example code:

```
var inview = new Waypoint.Inview({
    element: $('#inview-example')[0],
    enter:   function(direction) {
        notify('Enter triggered with direction ' + direction)
    },
    entered: function(direction) {
        notify('Entered triggered with direction ' + direction)
    },
    exit:    function(direction) {
        notify('Exit triggered with direction ' + direction)
    },
    exited:  function(direction) {
        notify('Exited triggered with direction ' + direction)
    }
});
```

It requires:

```
<script src="/path/to/lib/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/shortcuts/inview.min.js"></script>
```