# How to change class on scroll to current icon in vertical menu (onepage website)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have vertical menu (Divi theme - Wordpress). I to make an icon red (has class `active2`) when you are on section that belongs to that icon - menu item.

That works fine on click but I want that class goes to another icon that belongs to current section on scroll.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".fa-bars").addClass('active2');
  $(".fas").click(function() {
    $('.fas').not(this).removeClass('active2');
    $(this).addClass('active2');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="top-menu" class="nav">
  <li id="menu-item-36" class="ps2id menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-36"><a href="#section01"><i id="ikonabars" class="fas fa-bars active2"></i></a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-30" class="ps2id menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-30"><a href="#section02"><i id="ikonadom" class="fas fa-home"></i></a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-38" class="ps2id menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-38"><a href="#section03"><i id="ikonatools" class="fas fa-wrench"></i></a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-40" class="ps2id menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-40"><a href="#section04"><i id="ikonabook1" class="fas fa-book"></i></a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-41" class="ps2id menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-41"><a href="#section05"><i id="ikonainbox" class="fas fa-inbox"></i></a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-42" class="ps2id menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-42"><a href="#section06"><i id="ikonausers" class="fas fa-users"></i></a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-43" class="ps2id menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-43"><a href="#section07"><i id="ikonauserplus" class="fas fa-user-plus"></i></a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-39" class="ps2id menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-39"><a href="#section08"><i id="ikonabook2" class="fas fa-book-open"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

(I want that icon turn to red on scroll also - not click - when you scroll to #section03 should 3. icon get class active2 and turn to red)

Comment: So did you want the colour of the icon you have just clicked to turn red? And then also remove the red colour from the other icons?

Comment: That allready works fine. I want that icon turn to red on scroll also - not click - when you scroll to #section03 should 3. icon get class active2 and turn to red

Comment: Check [Add class when page scroll reach at specific id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34282580/add-class-when-page-scroll-reach-at-specific-id)